# Extract Patterns from the device log data

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, bayesian-networks

I am working on a project, in which we have to extract the patterns(User behavior) from the device log data. Device log contains different device actions with a timestamp like when the devices was switched on or when they was switched off.

```
For example:
When a person enters a room. He first switches on the light and then he 
switches on the fan or Whenever the temp is less than 20 C, he switches off
the AC.
```

I am thinking to use Bayesian Networks to extract these patterns.

- Learn Bayes Network from data (using Weka or Netica).
- Arcs in Bayes Network will give the patterns/dependencies among different devices.

  Is this the right approach ??

Edit: The chronological order between devices matters.

Comment: Is the chronological order important to you?

Comment: Yeah!! the chronological order matters. My aim is to extract rules from the data. In the above example, When the user enters a room. He first switches on the light and then he switches on the fan. Therefore based on the above information my rule is going to be whenever the user enters the room and if he switches on the light then the fan should get automatically switched on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the right approach?

**There's many possible approaches, but here's a very simple and effective one that fits the domain:**

Given the nature of the application, chronological order doesn't really matter, it doesn't matter if the `Fan` gets turned on before the `Light` e.g.

Also given that you can have e.g. a motion sensor to trigger a routine that reads the sensors, and perhaps a periodic temperature check, you can use the network below to act upon the extracted patterns (no need to complicate it further with chronological order and event tracking, we extract data to act upon, and event order in this domain isn't interesting)

> For example: When a person enters a room. He first switches on the
>   light and then he  switches on the fan or Whenever the temp is less
>   than 20 C, he switches off the AC.

Raw devices log might look something like this, T/F being True/False:

```
Person in room | Temperature | Light | Fan | AC
-----------------------------------------------
T              | 20          | T     | T   | T
T              | 19          | T     | T   | F
F              | 18          | F     | F   | F
```

With sufficient samples you can train a model on the above, e.g. Naive bayes is not sensitive to irrelevant features/inputs, so e.g. if you look at my first raw table above that includes all the variables and try to predict `AC`, with sufficient data it will understand that some inputs are not very important or completely irrelevant

Or if you know how before hand what the `Light`, `Fan`, and `AC` depend on, e.g. we know `Light` isn't going to depend on `Temperature`, and that `Fan` and `AC` don't care if `Light` is turned on or not (they can operate even if the person is sleeping e.g.) so you can break it down like below:

[image]

```
Person in Room | Light 
----------------------
T              | T
F              | F

Person in Room | Temperature | Fan
----------------------------------
T              | 20          | T
F              | 25          | F

Person in room | Temperature | AC
---------------------------------
T              | 20          | T
T              | 19          | F
F              | 20          | F
F              | 19          | F
```

Comment: But we don't know the dependencies between devices beforehand, It will be different for every user. We have to learn the dependencies from the data itself. Also, in future let's assume that the user switches on the fan no matter what temperature is then network should interpret this behavior and the edge between fan and temp should be removed. Basically, I am talking about a adaptive Bayes net which automatically adjust itself w.r.t. to the data.

Comment: Also, The chronological order matters.

Comment: It matters e.g. in an industrial process, in room appliances it doesn't matter if you turn the light first and the fan second or vice versa, the AC will principally depend on the temperature/humidity not that order
Any chronological pattern that gets dug up will be personal idiosyncrasies not functional patterns you want in automation

Comment: Ok!! but how to learn the dependencies using the data. Assume that we don't know anything and we want to learn the dependencies from the data itself. Like the AC (on/off) behavior will be dependent only on temp and humidity and not on anything else. Assume that temp and humidity data is present in device log

Comment: Naive bayes is not sensitive to irrelevant features/inputs, so e.g. if you look at my first raw table that includes all the variables and try to predict `AC`, with sufficient data it will understand that some inputs are not very important or completely irrelevant

Comment: I am planning to use Weka for Bayesian network structure learning.

Comment: Using Naïve Bayes!! - How can we know which of the inputs are important and which are not ?